# Can I coercion be used to generate constraints?

Tags: haskell

For debugging purposes I'd like to `show` some values nested in various parts of my program logic. It's not always the case, however, that what I'm trying to `show` has a `Show` instance. Is it possible to somehow assume that it does have a valid instance and defer the occurring from a potentially missing dictionary to run-time? I know I can add the constraint to the context of the function where I want to do the `show`ing, the caveat of this is that I may need to change many signatures throughout my program. I'm looking for functions like e.g.:

```
coerceTrace   :: forall a b . a -> b -> b
coerceTraceId :: forall a   . a -> a
```

That internally conjures up a `Show a` to be used with the `Debug.Trace` family of functions.

I know that we have `unsafeCoerce`, but it's not obvious to me if this can be used to generate constraints.

Comment: have you tried to use [ghci debugging](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-debugger) instead of printf-debugging, or even better written small test cases to catch the errors in your program logic?

Comment: GHC keeps no type information at runtime: types are erased during compilation. A parameter of generic type `a` is roughly passed as an untyped pointer. There's no way to use that argument in any way except passing it around / returning it, since to access the pointed data one needs to know its type, so to know how many bytes to read, and how to interpret them.

Comment: If you know the runtime type, and that is a `Show` type, you can use unsafe coercions to "cast" that value to the runtime type, after which you can use `Show`. This is a big "if", however.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to implement `coerceTraceId` with the type and behavior you request.

Comment: I'm curious if there's a good -- technical or otherwise -- reason for this. It seems to me that it would be quite helpful.

Comment: @fredefox Yes, the reason was described well by chi in the comments. For efficiency, the runtime representation of values does not store information about the type. `False :: Bool` and `LT :: Ordering` look the same in memory. Therefore it is not possible to "wish up" a `Show` instance -- it's not even possible to "wish up" a representation of the right type, let alone take the next step of finding a `Show` dictionary for that type.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're bold enough to ignore the comments, here's quite literally what you want to do, with a demonstration of how to crash GHCI with it.

```
$ stack install constraints
$ stack ghci
...
> :set -XTypeApplications
> import Data.Constraint
> import Unsafe.Coerce
> d = unsafeCoerce @(Dict (Show Int)) @(Dict (Show (Int -> Int))) Dict
> withDict d $ if False then show (\n -> n + 1 :: Int) else "Success! The Show constraint wasn't needed"
"Success! The Show constraint wasn't needed"
> withDict d $ show (\n -> n + 1 :: Int)
"<interactive>: internal error: PAP object entered!
    (GHC version 8.4.3 for x86_64_unknown_linux)
    Please report this as a GHC bug:  http://www.haskell.org/ghc/reportabug
$ # back to shell
```

Disclaimer: Don't do this. Even if you define your own `Show (Int -> Int)` instance at the top-level, GHC is free to ignore it and crash anyway.

Comment: Your `d` has monomorphic type, but the question asks about writing a function with polymorphic type.

Comment: Right. It won't actually generate you a `Show` instance for an unconstrained arbitrary type `a`.